# Interval of converge of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!(x+1)^n}{(2n-1)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the interval of converge of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!(x+1)^n}{(2n-1)!}$$

I will use the ratio test.

Let $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{n!(x+1)^n}{(2n-1)!}$

$\displaystyle a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)!(x+1)^{n+1}}{(2n + 1)!}$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)!(x+1)^{n+1}}{(2n + 1)!} \cdot \frac{(2n-1)!}{n!(x+1)^n}$$

$$\bigg| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{(n+1)(x+1)}{(2n+1)(2n)} \bigg|$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| = |x+1|\cdot\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n)} $$

Which evaluates to $0$

Therefore, the radius of convergence has to be $R = \infty$

So the interval of convergence is $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$

The book points out otherwise.

Comment: Your $a_n$ is given by $\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!}$ and not what you write. Otherwise your statement is ok (including the proof after adaption).

Comment: How? $a_n$ is the whole thing.

Comment: @frog, the book says this answer is wrong.

Comment: For $t>0$, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty~\frac{n!}{(2n)!}~(2t)^{2n} ~=~ \sqrt\pi~e^{t^2}~\text{erf}(t).$$ After differentiating both sides with respect to *t*, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty~\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!}~(2t)^{2n} ~=~ t~\bigg[2t+\sqrt\pi~(2t^2+1)~e^{t^2}~\text{erf}(t)\bigg],$$ where erf is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: No, but what is the radius of convergence

Answer (score 1):

My computation looks like this:
$$\begin{aligned} 
R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)(2n+1)}{n+1}=\infty,
\end{aligned}$$
so what does the book tell you then?

Comment: the book says interval of convergence: $x \in (-3, 1)$

Comment: So this must be a mistake in the book then. Lucians comment hints at the existence of a closed form of the series in terms of the error function, and this closed form is valid on all or $\mathbb R$.